# Need a middle machine to act like a browser proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a website (`bad-website.com`) that can only be accessed going through an ssh tunnel. I typically do this using a browser proxy with sock5. This is not great as everyone has to have the ssh tunnel+browser-proxy setup on their machines.

Ideally I would like the setup to be the following,

- user machine A
- middle machine B (url: `middle-machine.com` on our internal network)

and the user flow to be

- user machine A opens `middle-machine.com/do_something` in their browser
- the middle machine B acts like a browser proxy and somehow tunnels the request through the ssh tunnel on machine B and allows user machine A to access  `bad-website.com`

Would setting up an nginx forward proxy on machine B work for my usecase? Would this work exactly like a browser proxy?